# Como executar vídeos no android

Tags: android

Quero executar um vídeo em background como uma tela de Standby, escondendo controles do player etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite, o Android oferece uma API ampla para execução de medias, a forma mais fácil de você executar vídeos é usando o VideoView que é um wrapper do MediaPlayer e SurfaceView.

Exemplo simples, adicione o elemento VideoView no layout xml e no código Java:

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) 
                        findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    videoView.setVideoPath(
             "uri da mídia");

    MediaController mediaController = new 
        MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();
```